# How to switch the sweep layer (UW Map) on all selected objects at all once?

Tags: layers

[image]I was asked to clarify the question, okay.
There are many objects with the same number of sweep channels (UW Maps).
All sweep channels (UW Maps) on each object have the same name.
I need to select all objects with one selection in the scene and at the same time turn on, for example, the second sweep channel(UW Maps) on all selected objects .. Then turn on the third sweep channel(UW Maps) on all objects at the same time.
Blender cannot turn on the desired channel(UW Maps) on all objects at once.
You have to switch channels(UW Maps) one after another by selecting an object, but there are so many objects that it takes a long time only the process itself "selected an object, turned on the desired sweep channel(UW Maps), then selected the second object and turned on the same channel(UW Maps) again, then the third object was selected, the fourth and so on Further.."
Why not make it possible to select the desired sweep channel(UW Maps) on all objects that are selected in the scene?
[image]

Small but very important suggestions for improving Blender. I often use it, but I want it to be the standard in Blender, so as not to install addons.

I suggest adding such functionality to Blender. Very popular among modelers, but many do it through addons.
It works very simply, if among the objects the name of the map uw is the same, then the switch works on all objects. If the name of the uw map of some object does not match the names of the uw map on other objects, then the switch will only be where it matches, and for those that have different names, it will not switch there.

I also suggest adding 4 more buttons:

1. Create a uw map for all selected objects at once.
2. Delete the uw map for all selected objects at once.
3. Rename uw map which is selected for all selected objects at once.
4. Swap the uw map in the list, up or down, in relation to the neighbors. On purpose, I even found an addon that does this, but it would be cool if such simple functionality was standard in Blender.
   [image]

[image]

Switching the uw map on all selected objects at once should be automatic. Just selected all the objects and clicked on the desired uw map in the list.

Comment: I think you'll need to edit your question and explain what you mean by  "sweep layer" and "azerok name"! Someone may be able to help you once you've done that and explained your problem more clearly.

Comment: John is right, in English, I'm afraid this is currently incomprehensible. Please do your best to discover the meaningful terminology for what you're talking about.

Comment: I've corrected the text, look again at the question.